# Can you create multiple tests with the testng factory?

Tags: java, testng

Creating one test consisting of differenct test classes with different test methods is easy with the testng factory.

What I now want to do is creating multiple tests with the same test classes to run in parallel.

It would look like this if I would be doing it without factory:

```
<test name="testcombo1">
    <classes>
        <class name="test1" />
        <class name="test2" />
        <class name="test3" />
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="testcombo2">
    <classes>
        <class name="test1" />
        <class name="test2" />
        <class name="test3" />
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="testcombo3">
    <classes>
        <class name="test1" />
        <class name="test2" />
        <class name="test3" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

Of course it is more than 3 tests and each testcombo has different parameters. Those testcombos shall run in parallel not the classes or the methods. 
Is this possible using the testng factory? If not I am open for suggestions. If my question is not clear please ask.

**EDIT**

Suite created with XML Suite:

```
<suite thread-count="15" name="TmpSuite" parallel="tests">
  <!-- List of parameters for grid -->
  <listeners>
  <!-- some listeners -->
  </listeners>
  <test name="Accept2">
    <parameter name="number" value="2"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="com.Factory"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Accept2 -->
  <test name="Accept3">
    <parameter name="number" value="3"/>
    <classes>
     <class name="com.Factory"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Accept3 -->
  <test name="Accept4">
    <parameter name="number" value="4"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="com.Factory"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Accept4 -->
</suite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you generate your own testng.xml that does this? You can even do this in memory, look up the Javadoc fox XmlSuite.

Comment: Thanks Cedric looks like it is the right thing for me. Just got one more question can I run this from a suite? or do I have to run it programmatically?

Comment: You can invoke a testng.xml from a testng.xml file, look up the tag <suite-files> in the documentation.

Comment: I know the suite files tag ;-) The question is how to invoke the in memory suite creation, from a test? a factory?

Comment: I created a suite with tests with XmlSuite, but the tests aren't executed in parallel. What am I doing wrong? Edited my original post

Comment: Okay I found the problem. Each Test has the same class with a BeforeSuite method. This method gets only executed once. Using BeforeTest solves the problem